# Designing at 1024 x 768 resolution

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, resolution

I have a windows 8 app. The app consists of image buttons which are sort of distorted when I run them in a simulator with "1024 x 768" resolution.

The point being, I am not able to specifically design for that resolution, because my visual studio won't allow me to design at that resolution.

Looking at the picture will clear my exact description of the problem.

[image: resolution]

I am looking for the resolution 1024 x 768 in the drop down menu, but I can't find any.

Comment: Your image is a bit small so it's difficult to see what exactly you're referring to but have you tried embedding them in a viewbox set to fill and setting a common property like width or height only? This should retain your aspect ratio between the various resolutions when it's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR 1024*768 isn't a valid physical size. You should find it in the "there's something else snapped to the side" category (the second icon to the right of "View" and above "FullScreenLandscape").

Comment: I believe that's called "Snapped"; and I believe 1366X768 is the minimum target.

Comment: "Filled" was the word I was looking for ... ;-)

I was wrong anyway: 1024x768 is indeed a valid Metro resolution (no snap/fill for this resolution), so it should be listed in "fullscreen" category (I can't check right now). However I'd look in the "Filled" category nevertheless.

Comment: I can assure u - 1024 res ... exists
[Screenshot here](http://i.imgur.com/JaEKn.png)

I checked what you said, it's not there

Answer (score 0):

Look at the top of your image.  Do you see the view selector? The Visual State is Fullscreen.  Change that to the fill view (the 3/4 view) and you should see the 1024x768 view.

For further reference regarding Metro screen sizes, read: [this blogpost from Microsoft.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)

Edited 10/13

I see this on the simulator for my app even not in snapped view:
[image]

What version on VS are you running?  I am running Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL with  .NET c4.5.50709

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I have tried that before and tried that now as well. There is none! If you go to the fill view, it gives you 4 options rather than 6, the minimum res is 1366 x 768

Comment: You didn't get me man! I can see this view in the 'emulator' exactly what you have shown, but i cant get this view in the design mode - inside VS. I am using VS 2012.

Comment: Sorry HungryCoder.  I understand now, but how are you getting to the "Device" view within VS2012?  I've looked, but haven't found it yet?  I'll check to see what I've got.